# Linear Algebra Terminology Question

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What does the term $\mathcal{D}^{(3)}(\mathbb{R})$ mean?

I encountered the term in the context of this question in a class I am taking:

Let $W = \{f \in \mathcal{D}^{(3)}(\mathbb{R}) | f''' − 2f'' + 3f' − 4f = 0\}$. Is $W$ a subspace of $\mathcal{D}^{(3)}(\mathbb{R})$?

I stress that this is an assigned question related to a course I am taking, so I am *not* seeking a solution to this question, only an explanation regarding what the term noted above means (the set of which $f$ is a member).  I have never encountered it before.

Comment: 3 times differntiable functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Surb!

Comment: It is worth mentioning the space of thrice continuously differentiable real functions is often $C^3(\Bbb R)$ and $k$-times continuously differentiable as $C^k(\Bbb R)$, see [wolfram mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-kFunction.html) and wikipedia [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes) and [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Functional_analysis).  $C^\infty(\Bbb R)$ would correspond to the infinitely continuously differentiable functions and $C^0(\Bbb R)$ just refers to the continuous functions, regardless of differentiability.

Comment: Thank you.  One follow-up question - when we talk about an n-times-differentiable function, does differentiating the function zero count?  I am guessing not, since any polynomial (or constant) function would then be infinitely-differentiable, defeating the purpose of the terminology, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Oh, the zero function absolutely does count as being infinitely differentiable, as do all polynomials, exponentials, sines and cosines and several other examples.  The derivative certainly exists for them, even if it may not be particularly interesting or have changed.  Having derivative zero still counts as having a derivative.

Comment: Since you bring up the zero function and since you are looking at the vectorspace properties of this and related spaces, it is worth reminding that the zero function will indeed be the additive identity of these spaces.  The set of three-times differentiable function whose third-derivative is nonzero is not closed and has no additive identity.  Note that if $f$ were such a function, $-f$ would be as well and $f+(-f)=0$ would equal and have third-derivative zero.  It would fail to be a space.

Answer (score 1):

$D^{(3)}(\Bbb{R})\equiv D^{(3)}(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$ probably refers to the set of functions $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $f$ is thrice differentiable on $\Bbb{R}$, i.e $f',f'',f'''$ all exist (you can easily show that $D^{(3)}(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$ is a vector subspace of $\mathcal{F}(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$, the set of all functions $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$).